# AWS Cognito and SES not sending emails TO formerly unverified address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

A user in my AWS Cognito user pool created their account within Cognito BEFORE they SMS verified their own email address (Yahoo, if it matters).  They never received a confirmation email, and even after they verified their own email they aren't receiving any mail from these AWS services.  I have tried to delete and re-create their account via Cognito many times but they appear to be black-listed from receiving emails from AWS services.  Any advise or direction is appreciated.